# show spinner at the time of clicking edit text in Android?

Tags: android

when the user click the editText Field I need to show spinner(dynamic) from that user select any of the item i need to set the Text for Edit text .How to do this?

Comment: yes..you can go through what peter knego pointed it's exactly correct.

Comment: Reefer to my post bellow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266075/show-spinner-at-the-time-of-clicking-edit-text-in-android/14845943#14845943

Answer (score 8):

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

TextView textview_countries;

private String[] countries_list={"Philippines","Japan","Australia"};
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textview_countries=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview_countries);
    textview_countries.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); //To hide the softkeyboard


    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_countries = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries_list);

    textview_countries.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this)
                  .setTitle("Select Countries")
                  .setAdapter(spinner_countries, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        textview_countries.setText(countries_list[which].toString());
                      dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                  }).create().show();
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Don't roll this back again.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://wing-linux.sourceforge.net/guide/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html).

Comment: it will give the list at the time of edit/ giving user inputs.I need to show the items from the db and list to the user after item choose i wish to set the item text to the EditText

Comment: Yes it will. Just try the example in the link.

Answer (score 0):

`OnClick` of `TextView` I have taken the AlertDailog box consist of `MydataAdapter` in which i have passed `txt_show.setText(Arraylistdata[which].toString())` to show on the `TextView`

Follow this code:

```
txt_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Select More Categories")
                    .setAdapter(MydataAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            txt_show.setText(Arraylistdata[which].toString());

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
        }
        });
```